# What does Zap Proxy "HTTP Parameter Override" scan do?

Tags: zap

When I run a baseline scane on a target I get the following result:

```
docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -d -t https://mytarget.com
```

Result:

```
WARN-NEW: HTTP Parameter Override [10026] x 3
```

What does this result mean? What this scan is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting timing, this was just being discussed on the issue tracker the other day: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4454

The thread that started it all: http://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/owasp-leaders/2012-July/007521.html

Basically it has to do with forms that don't have actions, or that propagate GET paras into form actions. (Mainly impacting JSP/Servlet).

Edit: Of course you could also use the `-r report.html` (or any of the reporting options) to get full details vs. just the summary.

```
    -r report_html    file to write the full ZAP HTML report
    -w report_md      file to write the full ZAP Wiki (Markdown) report
    -x report_xml     file to write the full ZAP XML report
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So then in our case this is a false positive. Because target page relevant to above warning is a SPA loaded from an Apache server which doesn't handle any query parameters in the GET request.